# Update configure Jenkins in Docker container

Tags: maven, jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I have created a dockerfile, which install jenkins and install the plugins. Now my requirement is i have an updated "Configure Jenkins"xml. How to add this xml into jenkins container.

```
FROM jenkins
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y sudo \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
USER jenkins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

Comment: Is this XML located in the same directory as your Dockerfile?

Comment: yes.. it is located in the same directory

Comment: see the Dockerfile directive ADD and COPY , the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the following:

- You have created your own custom Jenkins image with your own Dockerfile.
- Now you have a running Jenkins Container based on your own custom image.
- Now you have a manual edited xml file and you want to copy this file inside the running Jenkins container.

Then use `docker cp` to copy the file inside the container with the name `yourcontainername`:

```
$ docker cp "Configure Jenkins"xml yourcontainername:/var/jenkins_home
```